# How do I address this error message in QGIS, "CSV file must be in UTF-8 encoding"?

Tags: qgis, csv, geocoding, error, mmqgis

When I attempt to use the MMQGIS geocoding plugin, I get the error message, "CSV file must be in UTF-8 encoding".

It causes the program not to respond for a few brief moments, then comes back with that error message.  Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

[Describes use of MMQGIS, a set of Python vector map layer plugins for Quantum GIS](http://michaelminn.com/linux/mmqgis/)

> MMQGIS assumes that input and output shapefiles and CSV files are encoded in the UTF-8 character set.
>
> MMQGIS uses the standard Python CSV file interface functions, which do not handle Unicode or other multi-byte encodings.
>
> While files that use the lower 7-bits of the 8-bit Windoze character sets (ISO-8859-x) will generally be fine, unpredictable results and errors may occur with non-ASCII characters in non-UTF-8 character sets.
>
> One way is to save a UTF-8 CSV from Excel.

[How can I save a csv with utf-8 encoding using Excel 2013?](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_windows8/how-can-i-save-a-csv-with-utf-8-encoding-using/12801501-c1e4-4a64-80d9-96b680b64cfe?auth=1)

A response provide there shows this as a solution:

> "One easy way to change excel ANSI encoding to UTF-8 is the open the .csv file in notepad then select File > Save As. Now at the bottom you will see encoding it set to ANSI change it to UTF-8 and save the file as new file and then your done. If someone has a program or script that can do this without notepad I sure would like to know how."

Also, [Problem with MMQGIS in QGIS V. 2.0.1 - Attribute Join from CSV File](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/84062/35779) may shed some light as well, even though it is not quite exactly like your question.